# IntelliJ not recognizing html tags in components of angular 7 project

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]
Starting html tags are showing up in red color complaining TSXXXX cannot find name, although project build and works alright.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebStorm HTML files are showing TypeScript errors for HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53966086/webstorm-html-files-are-showing-typescript-errors-for-html-elements)